# Only create taxonomy terms on node approval?

Tags: 6, workflows

Right now nodes on my site are unpublished by default because I want to manually approve user submitted content. How can I make it so that user submitted taxonomy terms are not created until I manually approve the corresponding node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with the taxonomy terms existing for a brief second then you can move them to a vocabulary otherwise unused on hook_nodeapi insert and, upon hook_nodeapi update if status flips from 0 to 1 then move them back to the vocabulary attached to the node.

```
  function mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
    switch ($op) {
      case 'insert':
        $tids = array_keys($node->taxonomy);
        $placeholders = db_placeholders($tids);
        db_query("UPDATE {term_data} SET vid = 654321 WHERE tid IN ($placeholders)", $tids);
        break;
      case 'update':
        if ($node->status) {
          db_query("UPDATE {term_data} SET vid = 23 WHERE tid IN (SELECT tid FROM {term_node} WHERE nid = %d)", $nid);
        }
 }
```

Where 654321 is a vocabulary you created but didnt assign node types to it and 23 is the vocabulary your nodes can use. This way the terms get created but other nodes cant use 'em, an appropriate View wouldn't see them etc. It's a hack. But a very effective hack.

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: Works if I use $tids = array_keys(taxonomy_node_get_terms($node));

Comment: Did you try to debug the $node object? Theoretically it has the taxonomy terms on it but I must admit I've forgotten the structure of it in D6.

Comment: I tried debugging the node object. It has the terms name as a string but no tid.

Comment: Also change $nid to $node->nid and it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, this would require a custom module. You would have to do something like this (tailor to your needs; I don't know if you're using publishing status to represent approval status).

```
    <?php
      function mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
        switch ($op) {
          case 'presave':
            if (!empty($node->taxonomy) && $node->status == 0) {
              // Write some logic to save the data to your module's DB table, e.g.
              // _mymodule_get_taxonomy_temp() would contain a database query or
              // something to get the record.
              $record = _mymodule_get_taxonomy_temp($node->nid);
              $record_exists = !empty($record);
              $taxonomy_temp = ($record ? $record : new stdClass());
              $taxonomy_temp->taxonomy = $node->taxonomy;
              $taxonomy_temp->nid = $node->nid;
              if ($record_exists === FALSE) {
                drupal_write_record('mymodule_taxonomy_temp', $taxonomy_temp),
              }
              else {
                drupal_write_record('mymodule_taxonomy_temp', $taxonomy_temp, 'nid'),
              }
              unset($node->taxonomy);
            }
            elseif (!empty($node->taxonomy_temp && $node->status == 1)) {
              // Retrieve the saved taxonomy and put it back into the node.
              $record = _mymodule_get_taxonomy_temp($node->nid);
              // We append it to any changes made during the approval process.
              $node->taxonomy = array_merge($node->taxonomy, $record->taxonomy);
              // Clean up the database record
              _mymodule_delete_taxonomy_temp($node->nid);
            }
            break;
        }
      }
    ?>
```

Note that this is strictly sample code. You might want to retrieve the terms using hook_form_alter instead and show them in the tags box as if they had been added. In any case, the key is not to have them in `$node` when `taxonomy_nodeapi()` runs and saves them.